# Упростить код JS (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

Как сократить скрипт?

```
 $('span.class_1').hover(function(){
  $('div.class_1').fadeToggle();
});
$('span.class_2').hover(function(){
  $('div.class_2').fadeToggle();
});
$('span.class_3').hover(function(){
  $('div.class_3').fadeToggle();
});
// И так далее... до 60 штук
```

**UPD**: В целом,  у меня есть `<li>` со вложенными `span` и `div`. При наведении на `span` этого `li` мне нужно отобразить `div`.

Comment: может проще нормальную разметку сделать вместо  кучи пронумерованных классов?

Comment: Неплохо было бы понимать для чего это делается. Сейчас у вас типичный индокод и от перебора в цикле числовых суффиксов классов он таковым быть не перестанет. Более грамотным было бы задавать связь между соответствующими `span` и `div` при помощи data-атрибутов или путем поиска соответствующего элемента в пределах родителя

Comment: Ну вот, как оказалось (судя по обновлению с li, span и div) - все эти классы воообще не нужны. Нужно просто чуть более глубокое освоение функций jquery и их применение (см ответ tutankhamun)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Теперь, когда известно про `span` и `div`, вложенные в `li` получается вот такая конструкция:

```
$('li span').hover(function() {
    $(this).closest('li').find('div').fadeToggle();
});
```

Чтобы не было разночтений вместо `span` и `div` следует использовать классы

Comment: Идеально! Всем спасибо!